# pfSense / FreeBSD sudden reboot - how to find out cause

Tags: freebsd, boot, pfsense

I've installed a pfsense router at home, and today it rebooted suddenly. I don't know why, didn't initiate it. In the system.log I don't find anything. In the System>General page and under NTP I can see the time of restart, but no cause.

How can I find out why this happened?

Comment: are kernel core dumps enabled? Is there a coredump on the swap partition? Other than that most likely local power outage

Answer (score 0):

Is the process of shutting down before reboot logged or just starting after it? Maybe it is a hardware issue. Running memest or cpuburn for a few days might show it.